# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre str.funcionDeString(); a String(str).funcionDeString();?

Tags: javascript

En algunos códigos he visto el uso de la funcion **replace** como lo siguiente.

```
var str = "Hola";
var converted = str.replace("a","o");
console.log(converted);
```

Y también he visto:

```
var str = "Hola";
var converted = String(str).replace("a","o");
console.log(converted);
```

Podrían indicarme cuál es la diferencia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente el único beneficio que le veo es que si utilizas `String(str)` no te va a lanzar ningún error si el `String` es nulo, en cambio, `str` te lanzará un error.

Con tus ejemplos:

```
var str = null;
var converted = str.replace("a","o");
console.log(converted); //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null(…)(anonymous function)

var str = null;
var converted = String(str).replace("a","o");
console.log(converted); //null
```

Answer (score 2):

Posibles Diferencias:

- Sí el valor es `NULL` o `undefined` al aplicar el [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace)  la primera forma arrojará un Error  `Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined` Haciendo incapié  que no se puede aplicar un [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace) a dicha varibale `NULA` o `Indefinida` mientras que la segunda Arrojará `NULL` o `undefined` dependiendo de como fue declarada e inicializada dicha variable.

  ```
  var str ;
  var converted = String(str).replace("1","2");
  console.log(converted); /* Ouput undefined*/

  var str ;
  var converted = str.replace("1","2");
  console.log(converted);/* Ouput Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined*/
  ```
- Hacer el `CAST`*(conversión)* de una Variable mediante `String(str)` nos permite asegurar el `replace` por si acaso el valor de una variable sea diferente a una cadena *(int , double)* obteniendo los mismos resultados si la variable es `NULL` o `undefined`

  ```
  var str =2.2;
  var converted = String(str).replace("2","4");
  console.log(converted); /* Ouput 4.2*/
  ```